# Missing 'Android SDK and AVD Manager' Button in Window Drop-Down Menu in Eclipse IDE...Any Ideas?

Tags: android

Just got a quick question. I'm looking to start developing for Android and I've installed the JDK SE 6 software development kit, the Eclipse IDE, the Android SDK, and the ADT Plugin for Eclipse. The only thing is, when it comes to the step where I'm supposed to select the specific Android platforms that I want to develop for, there is no combined 'Android SDK and AVD Manger' button on the 'Window' drop-down menu, only separate ones for the Android SDK and AVD, respectively. Not sure what I'm missing...any ideas? Thanks in advance.

See ya on the flipside,

Desh2350

Comment: AFAIK, that's the way it gets installed. I don't see any issues with that. I've been developing and I haven't faced any problems with Eclipse till date. Don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

Now there are two separate buttons. This is the update of adt v-14 I guess. Now you have separate buttons: one for AVD management and one for SDK management. Don't worry!

Comment: So, which do I go with to choose the platform I want to develop for? The book I have has a reference to a combined manager...

Comment: Using the SDK management button you can install platforms that are needed for your development. By default they are sorted by SDK version. In the AVD manager you can create and configure devices where to test your application

Answer (score 0):

That is because the adt plugin has been updated and now it includes two separate views, one which looks after the android packages installed or new packages available, and the other looks after the avd's created ...